# Async Multiple Database connections using fastapi?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Is it possible to do this in fastapi?
I have a lot of databases

```
engine2 = create_engine("mysql+asyncmy://db1")
engine4 = create_engine("mysql+asyncmy://db2")
engine3 = create_engine("mysql+asyncmy://db3")
engineN = create_engine("mysql+asyncmy://dbN")
```

i need to connect to them depending on the request. for example
I make a Post request

```
{user_id : 20; status: “ok”}
```

fastapi sets up a session with the user1-10k database, I make another request

```
{user_id : 20000; status : “close”}
```

fastapi sets up a session with the user10k-50k database.
The body contains the key on the basis of which the decision is made to connect to the database that needs to be connected. How to implement it?

this method does not work https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/persistence_techniques.html#coordination-of-transactions-for-a-multiple-engine-session

I came up with a solution, but it seems to me it may be wrong

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import text

list_engines = {
    '1': create_async_engine("mysql+asyncmy://db1", echo=True),
    '2': create_async_engine("mysql+asyncmy://db1", echo=True),
    #...
    
}


class User(BaseModel):
    user_id: int
    status: str


async def async_main(user: User) -> None:
    db = None
    if user.id<50:
        db = list_engines[1]
    else:
        db = list_engines[2]
    #....
    async_session = sessionmaker(list_engines[db], class_=AsyncSession)
    async with async_session() as session:
        stm = text("UPDATE users SET =:status WHERE id = :id")
        await session.execute(stm, {'id': user.id, 'status': user.status})
        await session.commit()


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/")
async def get_id(user: User):
    r = user_id = await async_main(user)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("__main__:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, reload=True)
```

Comment: The method from sqlalchemy docs doesn't work in what way exactly?

Comment: Why don't you have some sort of dispatch method that returns an appropriate db connection depending on the request parameters?

Comment: To add to @NotAName comment, you could implement it using FastAPI’s dependency injection. Create a dependency that returns the user id from the request payload, and create another dependency for the database session that depends on the previous one.

Comment: You probably don't have to have a separate dependency for user id at all, but can make your dependency that retrieves the db session depend on a `user_id` Body-parameter (make it optional, so that you can return the default database if a user_id parameter is not given).